# 500 internal server error in loading html page via NGINX on Ubuntu

Tags: html, ubuntu, nginx

I am working on `Ubuntu 18` and trying to render an `HTML` page via `NGINX`. Following [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) I did these steps:

1. Created html directory using `sudo mkdir -p /var/www/sample/html`
2. Placed my Web files directory `webui` under the `html` above
3. Created a nginx `conf` file using `sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/sample.conf`
4. Placed below in the `sample.conf`

   ```
   server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

       root /var/www/sample/html;
       index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

       server_name 123.54.67.235;
       location / {
         include proxy_params;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_buffering off;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
         proxy_pass http://localhost/webui/;

      }

      location /app {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://123.54.67.235:7000;

     }
   ```

   }
5. Created a link from it to the sites-enabled directory using `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/sample.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`
6. Un-commented `server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;`
7. Did `sudo nginx -t`. Got below message:

   ```
   nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
   nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
   ```
8. Did `sudo systemctl restart nginx`. No error came.

Now when I try to go to `http://123.54.67.235` from my browser, I get nginx `500 Internal Server Error`.

Not sure what's the mistake I am making as I am very new to and in-experienced with this. Can anyone suggest what's the reason for this?

**UPDATE**: When I go to my Nginx Error log I see below error there:

```
2019/05/05 05:52:51 [alert] 29779#29779: *2588 768 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, client: 123.54.67.235, server: 134.209.113.22, request: "GET /webui/webui/webui/webui/webui/webui/webui/webui/.....
```

**Note:** **I am using my server's ip address in the `server_name` field of conf file as I do not have a domain name assigned to my server.**

Comment: You need to look at the Nginx error log, which should explain the cause of the 500 error.

Comment: As mentioned, `500` is just the generic error your webserver shows the public, the logfile will include more info. You are working blind if you don't use your logs!

Comment: typically your nginx log lives in dir /var/log/nginx  ... look in your config for something similar to    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

Comment: @RichardSmith I have pasted the error I see in my Nginx logs above

Comment: `proxy_pass http://localhost/webui/;` is pointing to itself which means it's just generating an infinite number of `/webui/` path elements to the URI.

Comment: @RichardSmith so how should I point it to my html? I have kept my `webui` html directory under `/var/www/sample/html` and specified `root` in nginx configuration to `/var/www/sample/html`. I tried placing the `webui` html directory under `/var/www/html` as well which I believe is the default directory.

Comment: @RichardSmith and so my `proxy_pass` will remain as it is above or changed?

Answer (score 0):

The `proxy_pass http://localhost/webui/;` statement points into the same server and generates a recursive loop by adding an endless number of `/webui/` path elements. The `proxy_pass` directive is intended for a reverse proxy, and is used to forward requests to some other server.

To serve static content, you should use a `root` statement.

If the URI `/foo` should serve the file at `/var/www/sample/html/webui/foo`, use `root /var/www/sample/html/webui;`.

For example:

```
server {
    ...
    root /var/www/sample/html/webui;
    ...    
    location / { }

    location /app {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_...;
        proxy_pass ...;
    }
}
```

The `location /` block is empty.